# jquery alert box disabling the input box

Tags: jquery

i am using the jqalert.js,jquery-1.2.3.js,jqDnR.js to create alerts.The alert is displaying perfectly,but i have input boxes(text boxes),the alert message allowing to enter text in the input box.how we can disable the key events when the alert box is showing? please help me.

Thanks
Usman.sk

Answer (score 1):

If you use

`jqalerter.getEmptyOptions().setOption('modal', true).setOption('backgroundColor', 'white')`

as in

> Note that this current build still has
>   a few bugs and missing features. Among
>   the bugs is the use of
>   getEmptyOptions() and then setting
>   {modal: true} can have unpredictable
>   results, as demonstrated below.

from http://www.jondavis.net/codeprojects/jqalert/